# How can I make a single function work in multiple HTML buttons?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, button

I'm creating this size comparison tool just for practice since I'm new to JS.
I have multiple buttons in my HTML file (one for every US size) that once clicked should return the corrisponing UK, EU and CM size inside some empty `<div>` I created.

I actually managed to do it by giving each button a single id and writing a function for each one of them but it's a very inefficient and repetitive code, I'd like to understand how can I make it more efficient.

```js
const sizeAll = [
   {  US: 4,     UK: 3.5,   EU: 36,     CM: 22    },
   {  US: 4.5,   UK: 4,     EU: 36.5,   CM: 22.5  },
   //other size objects removed from here
   {  US: 14,    UK: 13,    EU: 48.5,   CM: 32    }   
];  


let sizeFour = document.getElementById('Four');
let sizeFourPointFive = document.getElementById('FourPointFive');

//all the other sizes removed from here

let sizeFourteen = document.getElementById('Fourteen');

let us = document.getElementById('current');
//uk
let uk = document.getElementById('uk');
let ukNumber = document.getElementById('ukNumber');
//eu
let eu = document.getElementById('eu');
let euNumber = document.getElementById('euNumber');
//cm
let cm = document.getElementById('cm');
let cmNumber = document.getElementById('cmNumber');


const comparison4 = () => {
   us.textContent = 'US' + ' ' + sizeFour.value + ':';
   uk.textContent = 'UK';
   ukNumber.textContent = sizeAll[0].UK;
   eu.textContent = 'EU';
   euNumber.textContent = sizeAll[0].EU;
   cm.textContent = 'CM';
   cmNumber.textContent = sizeAll[0].CM;
};

sizeFour.addEventListener('click', comparison4);
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
       <button id='Four' value="4">4</button>
       <button id='FourPointFive' value="4.5">4.5</button>
<!--I took out all the other buttons just for code exhibit purpose-->      
       <button id='Fourteen' value="14">14</button>
</div>

<div>
       <h2 id="current"></h2>
           <h3 id="uk"></h3>
               <p id="ukNumber"></p>
           <h3 id="eu"></h3>
               <p id="euNumber"></p>
           <h3 id="cm"></h3>
               <p id="cmNumber"></p>          
</div>
```

If I repeat this process (`comparison45()`, `comparison5()` etc.) in my JS file for 21 times (the number of my buttons) everything works, but in order to avoid repeting this process, how can I make this code efficient?

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/n1ow86uz/2/) is a pretty efficient way, reduces your code to what is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all the buttons a class so you can loop over them and assign the same listener function. The function can use `e.target` to get the button that was clicked on.

Change `sizeAll` to an object whose keys are the IDs of the size buttons.

```js
const comparison = (e) => {
  var size = sizeAll[e.target.id];
  us.textContent = 'US' + ' ' + e.target.value + ':';
  uk.textContent = 'UK';
  ukNumber.textContent = size.UK;
  eu.textContent = 'EU';
  euNumber.textContent = size.EU;
  cm.textContent = 'CM';
  cmNumber.textContent = size.CM;
};

document.querySelectorAll(".size").forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', comparison));

let us = document.getElementById('current');
//uk
let uk = document.getElementById('uk');
let ukNumber = document.getElementById('ukNumber');
//eu
let eu = document.getElementById('eu');
let euNumber = document.getElementById('euNumber');
//cm
let cm = document.getElementById('cm');
let cmNumber = document.getElementById('cmNumber');

const sizeAll = {
  Four: {
    US: 4,
    UK: 3.5,
    EU: 36,
    CM: 22
  },
  FourPointFive: {
    US: 4.5,
    UK: 4,
    EU: 36.5,
    CM: 22.5
  },
  //other size objects removed from here
  Fourteen: {
    US: 14,
    UK: 13,
    EU: 48.5,
    CM: 32
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button id='Four' class="size" value="4">4</button>
  <button id='FourPointFive' class="size" value="4.5">4.5</button>
  <button id='Fourteen' class="size" value="14">14</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h2 id="current"></h2>
  <h3 id="uk"></h3>
  <p id="ukNumber"></p>
  <h3 id="eu"></h3>
  <p id="euNumber"></p>
  <h3 id="cm"></h3>
  <p id="cmNumber"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about this IMO is to make use of the `event` argument passed to the `addEventListener` callback - in particular `event.target` which is a reference to the button that was clicked to trigger the event. If you do this you won't need to keep explicit variable references to each button in your code. Something like this:

```js
const sizeAll = [{
  US: 4,
  UK: 3.5,
  EU: 36,
  CM: 22
}, {
  US: 4.5,
  UK: 4,
  EU: 36.5,
  CM: 22.5
}, {
  US: 14,
  UK: 13,
  EU: 48.5,
  CM: 32
}];

let us = document.getElementById('current');
let uk = document.getElementById('uk');
let ukNumber = document.getElementById('ukNumber');
let eu = document.getElementById('eu');
let euNumber = document.getElementById('euNumber');
let cm = document.getElementById('cm');
let cmNumber = document.getElementById('cmNumber');

//Take advantage of the event argument that the browser passes to the addEventListener callback
const comparison = (e) => {
  //e.target.value is a reference to the button that was clicked to trigger the event
  const [sizeEl] = sizeAll.filter(size => size.US == e.target.value);
  //As a side note: there may be a better way to structure your data so you dont have to filter to find the correct array object - but for now this works

  us.textContent = 'US' + ' ' + sizeEl.US + ':';
  uk.textContent = 'UK';
  ukNumber.textContent = sizeEl.UK;
  eu.textContent = 'EU';
  euNumber.textContent = sizeEl.EU;
  cm.textContent = 'CM';
  cmNumber.textContent = sizeEl.CM;
};

document.querySelector('#Four').addEventListener('click', comparison);
document.querySelector('#FourPointFive').addEventListener('click', comparison);
document.querySelector('#Fourteen').addEventListener('click', comparison);
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button id='Four' value="4">4</button>
  <button id='FourPointFive' value="4.5">4.5</button>
  <!--I took out all the other buttons just for code exhibit purpose-->
  <button id='Fourteen' value="14">14</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h2 id="current"></h2>
  <h3 id="uk"></h3>
  <p id="ukNumber"></p>
  <h3 id="eu"></h3>
  <p id="euNumber"></p>
  <h3 id="cm"></h3>
  <p id="cmNumber"></p>
</div>
```